# Java garbage collection verbose not working

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have specified following verbose options but JVM is not printing any GC details to the log

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode 
-verbose:gc  -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

I am using java 1.8.0_05-b13

I tried some permutation and combination and noticed that only specifying

```
-verbose:gc  works and logs GC to stdout but following doesn't work

-verbose:gc  -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:GC.log
```

Comment: What code did you executed? Garbage collection may occur when many instances are created and lost links to them.

Comment: I can see garbage collection using jconcole but no GC logging

Answer (score 0):

The `-verbose:gc` switch makes the application print the GC details to stdout, so make sure that you try to read it from there. You can also use `-Xloggc:gcdetails.log` to print the details to an actual file instead.

Comment: I am using log4j to redirect all stdout to a file hence i am expecting it there.  Xloggc sounds like cleaner approach but i am not even getting logs on stdout

Comment: Also, using jconsole I checked memory bean and its verbose attribute is false

Comment: Maybe your application is not generating enough garbage. Try launching it with very low memory values (e.g. `-Xms2m -Xmx64m`) for force GC to run.

Comment: It is doing gc . i can see it in jconsole

Comment: Can you paste the command line you're running? Maybe it's an OS-specific issue.

Comment: Corrected my java version.  It turned out to be different than expected and also added more details about subsequent test.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but jconsole seems to hook into the JVM using JMX beans, while -verbose:gc simply prints directly to stdout from its C++ code and provides no access to it to Java.

Start it locally and look at the standard output to confirm or deny it.

Answer (score 0):

GC parameters were passed as Single string to ProcessBuilder. Sending each JVM argument as separate string to ProcessBuilder fixed it.